# Problem running CURL with the dns option

Tags: ubuntu, networking, dns, curl, webserver

I'm using curl for a while now to debug my non-prod web services.

When I'm using the `--dns-servers` option, I always receive an error that this feature was not found:

```
curl --dns-servers _MY_DNS_SERVER_IP_ https://_MY_DOMAINS_
curl: (4) A requested feature, protocol or option was not found built-in in this libcurl due to a build-time decision.
```

**My curl version is 7.47.0, running on Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop.**

From curl man page (about the `--dns-servers` option):

```
This option requires that libcurl was built with a resolver backend that supports this operation.
The c-ares backend is the only such one.  (Added in 7.33.0)
```

Is there another curl package that needs to be installed, or a some optional dependency that I missed?

Any hint what seems to be the problem ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `curl` binary that's built for Debian and Ubuntu doesn't contain support for libc-ares.  That's because that library [can't return](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2009-08/0014.html) both A (IPv4) and AAAA (IPv6) queries in a single response, so if the host you're connecting to uses IPv6 but you don't have IPv6 support, the connection just fails.  Since this is a pretty big defect (since many open Wi-Fi access points don't have IPv6), Debian and Ubuntu have compiled it out.

You may be able to get by with using `--resolve` to manually specify the IP addresses you want to use.  Otherwise, if you need to use this feature, you'll have to compile your own curl.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I spent a great amount of time trying to find a reasonable answer. Do you know some workaround that may help? `--resolve` is a bit like `/etc/hosts`, but I need something more dynamic without touching my main DNS (and force the usage of my secondary DNS)

Comment: You can set `/etc/resolv.conf` to use a specified resolver, possibly as a backup, but that's the only thing I can think of.